# Как определить search на странице по словам?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть такой html:

```html
<a href="#index">
  <span class="api-endpointlist-request-type">&#10061; GET /api/reports.json</span>
</a>
<hr>
<a href="#show">
  <span class="api-endpointlist-request"></span>
  <span class="api-endpointlist-request-type">&#10061; GET /api/reports/#{report_id}.json</span>
</a>
<h1>Report properties</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>category:</td>
    <td><b>"category": "custom_app_reports"</b><br> The category for the report. When you create a report, the API will return <code>custom_app_reports</code>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id:</td>
    <td><b>"id": {your_id_reports}</b><br> The unique numeric identifier for the report.</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name:</td>
    <td><b>"name": "My App Report"</b><br> The name of the report. Maximum length: 255 characters.</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>shopify_ql:</td>
    <td><b>"shopify_ql": "SHOW sales BY country FROM order SINCE -1m UNTIL today ORDER BY sales"</b><br> The ShopifyQL query that generates the report. See <a href="https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/shopify-ql" target="_blank">Shopify Query Language</a>.</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>updated_at:</td>
    <td><b>"updated_at": "2008-02-01T19:00:00-05:00"</b><br> The date and time <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601" target="_blank">(ISO 8601)</a> when the report was last modified.</td>

  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<h1>Endpoints</h1>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>GET</th>
    <th colspan="2">/api/reports.json</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Retrieves a list of reports created by your app</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ids:</td>
    <td>A comma-separated list of report IDs.</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>limit</td>
    <td>he amount of results to return.<br> (

      <code>default: 50, maximum: 250)</code></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>page:</td>
    <td>The page of results to show.<br> (

      <code>default: 1)</code></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>since_id:</td>
    <td>Restrict results to after the specified ID.</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>updated_at_min:</td>
    <td>Show reports last updated after date. (format: 2014-04-25T16:15:47-04:00)</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>updated_at_max:</td>
    <td>Show reports last updated before date. (format: 2014-04-25T16:15:47-04:00)</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fields:</td>
    <td>A comma-separated list of fields to include in the response.</td>

  </tr>
</table>
<h1>Retrieve a list of all reports</h1>
<p>GET /api/reports.json</p>
<b>Headers</b><br>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>Content-Type:</td>
    <td><b>application/json</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Authorization:</td>
    <td><b>{Your_Token_Key}</b></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view-report">
                                View response
                            </button>
<hr>

<div id="view-report" class="collapse">
  <hr>
  <code>
                                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK<br>
                                    {<br>
                                    "reports": [<br>
                                    {<br>
                                    "id": 752357116,<br>
                                    "name": "Custom App Report 2",<br>
                                    "shopify_ql": "SHOW total_sales BY country FROM orders ORDER BY total_sales",<br>
                                    "updated_at": "2018-07-05T12:41:00-04:00",<br>
                                    "category": "custom_app_reports"<br>
                                    },<br>
                                    {<br>
                                    "id": 517154478,<br>
                                    "name": "Wholesale Sales Report",<br>
                                    "shopify_ql": "SHOW sales BY country FROM order WHERE channel.api_client_id = 123 SINCE -1m UNTIL today",<br>
                                    "updated_at": "2017-04-10T16:33:22-04:00",<br>
                                    "category": "custom_app_reports"<br>
                                    }<br>
                                    ]<br>
                                    }
                                </code>
</div>
<h1>Retrieve a list of id reports</h1>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>GET</th>
    <th colspan="2">/api/reports/548698754.json</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Retrieves a single report created by your app</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fields:</td>
    <td>A comma-separated list of fields to include in the response.</td>

  </tr>
</table>
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <td>Content-Type:</td>
    <td><b>application/json</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Authorization:</td>
    <td><b>{Your_Token_Key}</b></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewid-report">
                                View response
                            </button>
<hr>
<div id="viewid-report" class="collapse">
  <hr>
  <code>
                                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK<br>
                                    {<br>
                                    "report": {<br>
                                    "id": 517154478,<br>
                                    "name": "Wholesale Sales Report",<br>
                                    "shopify_ql": "SHOW sales BY country FROM order WHERE channel.api_client_id = 123 SINCE -1m UNTIL today",<br>
                                    "updated_at": "2017-04-10T16:33:22-04:00",<br>
                                    "category": "custom_app_reports"<br>
                                    }<br>
                                    }
                                </code>
</div>
```

Как при клике a href  GET /api/reports.json автомат пошол вниз на ето строку?

Comment: Какой автомат куда должен идти?

Comment: автоматически курсор пошол вниз

Comment: Какой курсор? Вы хотите мышкой двигать?

Comment: да мишка пошол вниз по данную строку после клика

Comment: С помощью js нельзя двигать мышкой.

Comment: а как можно ето делать

Comment: В контексте вашего вопроса - никак нельзя.